# Bitcoin password help,

Tags: wallet-recovery, passphrase

i had a bitcoin qt wallet in 2013, ii have 2 backup wallet.dat files still, i believe 1 was backup off windows laptop and the other off apple Mac.i no longer have either of the computers or any other files other than the 2 backups.
i have just restored these backups into bitcoin core V26 and synced to the blockchain and it shows the curent balance and all transaction history.

i am not great with computers so even trying to follow the btcrecovery method confuses me.

i have read most of the similar questions on here and none really cover what i need, obviously if i could get the passphrase recovered that would be perfect but i understand why they have made it not possible to do that.

however i have a fairly good idea of what my password is to the point where if i knew how many characters it was i would know what it was and would only need to nut out which were capitals and lower case. the passphrase is between 26 and 34 characters long, can someone tell me is it possible to narrow down to an exact number of letters which would give me the phrase and then just brute force to work out capitals lower case and special character,

Comment: Oh I seem to have the wallet addresses also from the transaction list it shows me my account.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to narrow down to an exact number of letters

Modern systems of encryption are designed so that the encrypted data does not reveal key length - doing so would be regarded as a weakness making the scheme more vulnerable.